# lein bootstrap: stable release of leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Whenever I try to run `lein bootstrap` in the  `leiningen-core/` directory I always get the following message:

```
Please run "lein bootstrap" in the leiningen-core/ directory
with a stable release of Leiningen. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
```

I have the 2.2.0 script (which is a stable release). I have placed lein in my path. I am using
Linux (CentOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bootstrap` is only necessary if you are building lein from source. If you downloaded a stable release, it Just Works. So you can do things like `lein new`, `lein jar`, etc, with no further setup. See the excellent [README](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/README.md) for details.

Set your path correctly. For example, put the lein script in your ~/bin and then add ~/bin to your path environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However when I still try to run lein uberjar I get to see the same message: Leiningen is missing its dependencies.